# Write a Twilio completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, twilio

I am writing a completion handler which is designed by twilio

```
func initializeClientWithToken(token: String) {
    var accessManager = TwilioAccessManager(token:token, delegate:self)
    let properties = TwilioChatClientProperties()
    TwilioChatClient.chatClient(withToken: token, properties: properties, delegate: self, completion: {(_ result: TCHResult, _ chatClient: TwilioChatClient) -> Void in

    } as! TCHTwilioClientCompletion)
```

this is the code, when I run it, it appears "EXC_BREAKPOINT(CODE = 1 SUBCODE = XXXXX)" in the last line "as! TCHTwilioClientCompletion)"

I check up TCHTwilioClientCompletion which truly contains two items such as TCHResult and TwilioChatClient. But why it is not working.

Thanks for your answer

I recall something, do I need to initialise the object TwilioChatClient?

Comment: Remove `as! TCHTwilioClientCompletion` and check what the compiler is telling you, you shouldn't do the cast there

Comment: The cast is what the complier tell me to do

Comment: Just check at the break point and in the console whether it is telling you about something being nil

Comment: I am agreed with Kerry. There should be something I missed. ill debug again

Comment: The compiler does a dumb thing at this moment, it should be possible to pass as an argument without a cast